# 404 error when making ajax call to asp.net MVC controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make an ajax request to an MVC controller but I keep getting a 404 error whenever I try execute my script.

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`
`https://localhost:44301/LocationMapping/Test`

My request just returns `error get` from the code snippet below.

---

The structure of the relevant files in my project are

View where request is called -> `courselister/index.cshtml`

View's Controller -> `CourseListerController.cs`

My Controller for handling Ajax requests from the above view-> `LocationMappingController.cs`

---

The reason I am handling the requests from a different controller is because several views will use the same requests and so it seems better to keep these all together in `LocationMappingController`.

Here is the code for my ajax request

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
            url: "/LocationMapping/Test",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {},
            error: function (error) {
                alert('error get');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert('GET success');
                alert(data);
            }
        });
});
```

Here is the code in the LocationMapping Controller

```
public JsonResult Test() {
{
    return Json("Get Test", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

---

My current theory is that the server cannot find the route `/LocationMapping/Test` because it is not it the view's controller (`CourseListerController.cs`). It has taken a long time for me already to find a solution and so I am turning to the SO community to help.

Any help is appreciated.

---

Update: I tried creating a new controller and a view associated with it as follows,

TestAjaxController.cs

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public JsonResult GetResponse(string str)
{
    return Json(str, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

TestAjaxController/Index.cshtml

```
<div> 
    <h1>Test Ajax Page: Location Mapping</h1>
    <button onclick="callAjax()">Click Me</button>
    <script>
        //document.ready(function () {
            console.log('jquery loaded');
            function callAjax() {
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    alert("called");
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: "/TestAjax/GetResponse",
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { str: "this is the string I want to get as a response" },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("Error occurred calling GetResponse");
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert(data);
                        }
                    });
                });         
            }            
    </script>
</div>
```

and this works! I get prompted with the "this is the string I want to get as a response". I don't understand why it works when my other controller will not..

Comment: You've verified that your server is listening on port 44301? Can you get an ACK from the server on that port?

Comment: try to  use `url: '@Url.Action("Test","LocationMapping")',` instead of  `url: "/LocationMapping/Test",`, same result?

Comment: Don't you have to call your port number in your URL? It's been a long time for me...

Comment: I still receive the same 404 status when using the @Url suggestion :(

Comment: What happens when your enter `/LocationMapping/Test` in the address bar? Are you using Areas?

Comment: when I go to https://localhost:44301/LocationMapping/Test I get an error. I am not using any Areas.

Comment: And to confirm, you are using https:// ?

Comment: try this `'../LocationMapping/Test'`

Comment: This also returns a 404.

Comment: Are you sure your `LocationMappingController` is `public`?

Comment: yes it is public - `public class LocationMappingController : Controller`

Comment: I doubt this is your issue, but why are you passing an empty object as your data? I would remove this line: `data: {},`

Comment: no change i am afraid. Still 404 :(

Comment: I'm inclined to believe that the code is correct and the issue lies with the routing.

Comment: If you can't manually browse to your problematic page, you absolutely need to fix that, first. What does your RouteMap look like? Can you create a brand new controller and reproduce the problem? Is the Controller an ApiController or a regular Controller?

Comment: I can browse fine to the courselister/index page. I can't browse to a page for the LocationMapping controller as it doesn't have any corresponding views. The controller is not an ApiController as shown in an earlier comment.

Comment: updated question. I tried an ajax call with a new controller and view and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue. Closed the localhost tab in browser and ran start without debugging. I was able to view the JSON data in the route.